# SOAP server couldn't work correctly behind some proxy/firewall

Tags: delphi, soap, proxy, windows-7-x64

I have a SOAP server/client application written in Delphi XE working fine for some time until a user who runs it on Windows 7 x64 behind a corporate proxy/firewall. The application sends and receives TSOAPAttachment object in the request.

The Problem:

- Once the first request from this user is received and processed, the server could not process any request (from any user) successfully coming after this.
- The server still response to the request, but the SOAPAttachment of the request 
  seems corrupted after the first one from this user, that's why it couldn't process the request successfully.
- After putting may debug logs to the server, I noticed the TSOAPAttachment.SourceStream in the request's parameter become inaccessible (or empty), and TSOAPAttachment.CacheFile also empty. Therefore whenever trying to use the SourceStream, it will return Access Violation error.
- Further investigation found that the BorlandSoapAttachment(n) file generated in the temp folder by the first request still exist and locked (which should be deleted when a request is completed normally), and BorlandSoapAttachment(n+1) files of the following request are piling up.
- The SOAP server will work again after restarting IIS or recycle the application pool.
- It is quite certain that it is caused by the proxy or the user’s networks because when the same machine runs outside this networks, it will work fine.
- To add more mystery to the problem, running the application on WinXP behind the same proxy have no problem AT ALL!

Any help or recommendation is very appreciated as we have stuck in this situation for some time.

Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really sure that you debugged all your server logic that handles the attachments to attempt do discover any piece of code that could failed specifically on Windows 7, I would suggest:

1) Use some network sniffer [Wireshark is good for this task](http://www.wireshark.org/), make two subsequent requests with the same data/parameters values, and compare the HTTP contents. This analyze should be done both in the client (to see if the data is always leaving the client machine with the same content) and also in the server, to analyze the incoming data;

2) I faced a similar situation in the past, and my attempts to really understand the problem was not well succeed. I did workaround the problem sending files as Base64 encoded strings parameters, and not using the SOAP attachments. The side affect of using Base64 its an increase of ~30% in the data size to be sent, and this could be significant if you are transferring large files.

Remember that SOAP attachments create temp files in the server, and Windows 7 has different file access rules than Windows XP. I don't know if this could explain the first call being processed ant the others not, but maybe there are something related with file access.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is UAC (User Access Control) problem under Win 7. Try running the client in win 7 "As Administrator" and see if it is working properly.

Comment: but the same machine and same user settings running outside its corporate network works fine, so it is almost certain it is the proxy/firewall. but i couldnt explain why on happen on Win7, does win7 act differently on corporate network?